# How to separate a sentence into words

Tags: r, words, sentence

In r, I'm currently working with datasets of conversations. The data currently looks like the following:

```
Mike, "Hello how are you"
Sally, "Good you"
```

I plan to eventually create a word cloud of this data and would need it to look like this:

```
Mike, Hello
Mike, how
Mike, are
Mike, you
Sally, good
Sally, you
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with R so I do not know much. Previously when I only had the long strings and no name attached to them, I did

thing1 <- strsplit(df, " ")

df1 <- data.frame(thing1 = unlist(thing1))

Comment: Your title is not really representative of what you're trying to do. "How to separate a sentence into words" or similar would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this using `reshape2::melt`?

```
# Sample data
df <- read.csv(text =
    'Mike, "Hello how are you"
    Sally, "Good you"', header = F)

# Split on words
lst <- strsplit(trimws(as.character(df[, 2])), "\\s");
names(lst) <- trimws(df[, 1]);

# Reshape into long dataframe 
library(reshape2);
df.long <- (melt(lst))[2:1];
#     L1 value
#1  Mike Hello
#2  Mike   how
#3  Mike   are
#4  Mike   you
#5 Sally  Good
#6 Sally   you
```

Explanation: Split trailing/leading whitespace-trimmed (`trimws`) entries in second column on whitespace `\\s` and store in `list`. Take `list` entry names from first column, and reshape into a long `data.frame` using `reshape2::melt`.

I leave turning this into a comma-separated `data.frame` up to you...

Comment: Why the downvotes? This *does* provide a valid solution, and should get OP on track.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the OP didn't show enough evidence of attempt.  Maybe it is a discouragement of supporting that type of ethics.

Comment: @JosephK. Ok; I agree with the lack of own initiative from OP; that's why I decided to give a solution outline plus explanation, rather than a complete solution.

Comment: @JosephK. The question has an explicit input and a desired output, which is better than 95% of R questions and enough to not close it as no reprex. Some failed attempts would be nice, yes, but this is not even in the bottom half of questions, particularly for a first one. Especially for new users, it's important to teach how to ask a better question, not just downvote the questions to oblivion, demoralizing someone who doesn't know better yet.

Answer (score 3):

Use a tokenizer, e.g. via `tidytext::unnest_tokens`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

dialogue <- read_csv(
    'Mike, "Hello how are you"
     Sally, "Good you"', 
    col_names = c('speaker', 'sentence')
)

dialogue %>% unnest_tokens(word, sentence)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   speaker  word
#>     <chr> <chr>
#> 1    Mike hello
#> 2    Mike   how
#> 3    Mike   are
#> 4    Mike   you
#> 5   Sally  good
#> 6   Sally   you
```